# Study materials for Decision feedback equalizer

Tags: reference-request, equalizer

Looking for books, course notes/slides, or some tutorials on decision feedback equalizers with in-depth details.
I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

Not a comprehensive source of details, but for me [this paper/tutorial](https://doi.org/10.1109/PROC.1985.13298) has been the most helpful in terms of principles explanation. Also [here](https://github.com/Mamoutova/DFE) you can find a basic working example of DFE implementation in python, that you may find helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some good material:

Cioffi
https://cioffi-group.stanford.edu/doc/book/chap5.pdf

Vaidyanathan
https://authors.library.caltech.edu/25063/1/S00086ED1V01Y200712SPR003.pdf